# Retopology question

Tags: topology

so I am new to this whole retopology thing and I don't know if this is a good topology for the underside of an octopus. It would be great to get some feedback from people! :)[image]

Comment: Is it causing any issues? Are you satisfied with the result? If yes then it is a good topology for you. Unless you state a specific goal this is an opinion based question.

Answer (score 1):

Your mesh has a lot of edge loops, is it necessary?

Actually it depends on what you want. If you want a lot of details like bumps and irregularities, you'll need this amount of edge loops, if you want something smooth, you don't need as many edge loops and you can delete a lot of them.

It will also depend on the armature that you'll put inside if it happens.

However, whatever you do, it looks like you could delete some edge loops in the centre. Also, perhaps some parts like the skin between the tentacles could be improved...

You can also keep a low poly version of your mesh, then create a high poly, sculpt the high poly (with the sculpt tools or just by pulling the vertices), then create a Normal map from the high poly that you'll use on the low poly material to artificially simulate bumps and details.

Comment: Yeah, I was going for more of smooth, I might do bumps later, but to get smooth curves of the tentacles, I wonder how many loops are required?

Comment: I guess you must try, delete some edge loops and look what happens, if it doesn't change your tentacle a way you don't want, it means that the edge is useless